# How to get text between HTML tags

Tags: c#, html, split

I have this string:

```
<div class="type bold s11 upper"></div>
    <div class="s20 red">68.000.000 kr.</div>
    <div class="remem">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkRemember_d6b706eaeb544dd6a319bc9d64db7f4e"/>
    <label for="chkRemember_d6b706eaeb544dd6a319bc9d64db7f4e" class="gray bold s11 upper">Husk</label></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

But I only want 68.000.000 kr.

How can I delete everything in the string except `68.000.000 kr.`?

Comment: I don't think that shows how to isolate a string.

Comment: Possible yes. I just can't get it working when I have multiple tags. Code sample would be highly appreaciated.